# Reading csv file throws error fs.readFileSync) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like read a csv file from downloads folder and copy as json to fixture folder. I am getting below error  `_fs.readFileSync is not a function` When I set a break point I could see csv file getting undefined at step `const csvFile = readFileSync(file_name, "utf8");`
`Error:`
TypeError: (0 , _fs.readFileSync) is not a function

Could someone advise about the problem here ? I was following the below link to read the CSV file.

https://medium.com/@you54f/dynamically-generate-data-in-cypress-from-csv-xlsx-7805961eff55

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from "fs";
import { parse } from "papaparse";
const path = require('path');

        try {
        debugger;
        const __dirname = "C:/Users/Some_User/Downloads/"
        const file_name = path.join(__dirname, "catalogueExport.csv");
        const csvFile = readFileSync(file_name, "utf8");
        const csvResults = parse(csvFile, {
          header: true,
          complete: csvData => csvData.data
        }).data;
    
        cy.writeFile('tests/cypress/fixtures/testDataFromCSV.json', csvResults);
        // writeFileSync(
        //   "tests/cypress/fixtures/testDataFromCSV.json",
        //   JSON.stringify(csvResults, null, 4),
        //   "utf-8"
        // );
      } catch (e) {
        throw Error(e);
      }
```

[image]

Comment: `fs` only exits in `node.js`, not in browser's javascript

Comment: @namgold any possible way to read the CSV file in client side

Comment: Use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and let user browse the file for you. And no, there's no other way to access a local file at client side using JS.